# How to calculate the difference between two dates and percentage of the remaining days?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

In my react project i need to calculate the number of days remaining between two dates.That is i just want to calculate how many days remaining from today to expiry date.Then i want calculate percentage of this remain days and according to that i want to find the price.

That is i have a plan, monthly cost is $500.If a customer purchased it's on mid of the month ie, if there are 15 days remaining then the price for the plan should be 50% of monthly charge.Like wise.

what i did is:

```
 const currentExpiry = license.current.expiry,//this is like 2021-08-01T10:23:18.275Z
       now = moment(),
       periodEnd = moment(currentExpiry);
 
  const daysRemaining = now.diff(periodEnd, "days");
  console.log("daysRemaining", daysRemaining);//here getting like -9
```

How should i calculate that percentage?

Comment: The code you present results in 428, not -9 ... which makes sense, since  20 May 2020 is definitely in the past

Comment: @Bravo sorry it is my bad. now i edited the code.Please check

Comment: To calculate a percentage you need a total. Given what you posted, what would be that total?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution

```js
const currentExpiry = '2021-08-01T10:23:18.275Z'; //this is like 2021-08-01T10:23:18.275Z
const now = moment();
const periodEnd = moment(currentExpiry);
const costMonth = 500;

const daysRemaining = Math.abs(now.diff(periodEnd, "days"));

const daysOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').format('DD');

const cost = (costMonth / daysOfMonth * daysRemaining).toFixed(2);

console.log(`For ${daysRemaining} remaing days the cost is of ${cost}$'`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentExpiry = license.current.expiry;
now = moment();
periodEnd = moment(currentExpiry);
daysRemaining = Math.abs(now.diff(periodEnd, "days"));
daysOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').format('DD');
percentageOfRemainingDays = (daysRemaining / daysOfMonth) * 100;
console.log(`Remaining days :${daysRemaining} and percentage of remaining days :${percentageOfRemainingDays}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The portion remaining is `(end - now) ÷ (end - start)` where the differences are expressed in days. Multiplying the fee by the portion gives the pro rata fee.

```js
let today = moment().startOf('day');
let start = today.clone().startOf('month');
// To exclude last day of month in prorata fee
let end   = today.clone().endOf('month');
// To include last day of month in prorata fee
// let end   = start.clone().add(1, 'month');
let fee = 500;
let proRataFee = end.diff(today, 'days') / end.diff(start, 'days') * 500;

let f = 'ddd DD MMM';
console.log('Start   : ' + start.format(f) +
          '\nEnd     : ' + end.format(f) + 
          '\nFee     : ' + '$' + fee +
          '\nToday   : ' + today.format(f) +
          '\nPro rata: ' + '$' + proRataFee.toFixed(2)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This will return the full fee on the 1st of the month and $0 on the last day of the month. If you want to charge for the last day as well, make the end the start of the following month.